# Зависает программа при выводе данных в textlabel

Tags: c++, qt, консоль, bat, qwidget

Есть программа, которая запустит скрипт установки модулей для python (bat файл)

```
@echo off
chcp 1251
cls
set /P var="Введите название модуля, который нужно установить:"
cd /d "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts"
pip install %var%
pause
```

И моя программа должна запустить этот файл и вывести в textLabel всё, что выводит этот файл. Вот программа:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QProcess>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    QString program = "PyModuleInstaller.bat";
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "absads";

    QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(this);
    myProcess->start(program, arguments);
    myProcess->waitForFinished();
    connect(myProcess, &QProcess::readAllStandardError, [&]() {
        ui->label->setText( myProcess->readAllStandardError() );
    });
}
```

И при нажатии на кнопку программа зависает, потом секунд через 15 возвращается. И в textLabel ничего нет (хотя установка модуля absads вызывает ошибку). Как мне сделать вывод ошибок в textLabel (или что-то похоже)?

Comment: Создайте отдельный поток QThread, в нем код с QProcess и выполните, только вместо `ui->label->setText` нужно сигналом отправить данные в `label`. Кст, если данных много, то имеет смысл в `QPlaintTextEdit` их отправлять

Comment: Не нужен тут тред. На readyread переписать лучше

Comment: И уберите паузу из батника

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приложение зависает потому что в процессе у вас стоит команда `pause` программа должна отвиснуть когда эта пауза завершится, но так как у Вас нет кода, которому эта пауза нужна - её можно убрать.

По поводу зависания на 15 секунд - нужно переписать на сигнал readyRead - так вывод процесса будет появляться на экране постепенно. Но на pip могут быть использованны управляющие последовательности, поэтому вывод может получится загрязнен. Под виндовс не так сильно(надо проверить как работает `\r` на `QLabel`)

Насчет `set` в батнике тоже не уверен... Ввод и аргументы это разные вещи.